# Sending data from view.py to a javascript in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, pandas

I know similar questions have been asked before but I am very new to django and js. I have tried many solutions but I am not able to make sense of many and able to run them. So I am writing my code and the solution that I have tried. Can someone please tell me what mistake am I doing.

In my `views.py` I am handling a file which produces some results. These results are in the form of a Dataframe(used pandas). From this dataframe I am calculating few integer values which are stored in variables: `tot,p,lp,us`. I am also getting 3 sub-dataframes namely: `dfp,dflp,dfus`. I need to display all these on the webpage so I am sending them to an html: `uploaded.html` as shown below.

```
   dict_1 = {'Path':p, 'LPath':lp, 'USig':us}
   json1 = json.dumps(dict_1)

   return render(request, 'uploaded.html', locals(), {'js_json1': json1, 'TotVar': tot})
```

The above code just sends the variables and not the dataframe as I don't know how to do it. I have handled it in my `uploaded.html` in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload File-Hereditary Cancers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function results()
                {
                 var totalvariants = {{TotVar}};
                document.getElementById("totvar").innerHTML = "Total number of variants are: "+totalvariants;
                }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Hereditary Cancers</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="uploadfile.html">Upload File</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="team.html">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      {% if saved %}
         <strong>Your file was uploaded.</strong>
                 <button onclick = "results()">Results</button>
                 <p id = "totvar">This will change</p>
      {% endif %}

      {% if not saved %}
         <strong>Your file was not uploaded.</strong>
      {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div id="connect">
                <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/facebook/" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a><a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/googleplus/" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a><a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/twitter/" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/misc/contact/" target="_blank" class="tumbler"></a>
            </div>
            <p>
                © 2023 Zerotype. All Rights Reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am creating a button in my html which activates the script on click. I haven't done much in my script because I don't know how to. I have just tried to display the tot variable which is also not getting displayed.Can anyone tell me the complete script on how I can handle dataframes and variables in my js function and display their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what are you do, but you send locals() as context. first, why you did this? you don't use them in template. second, you should send your context in third parameter in render() and if you so need locals in template context, write something like this:

```
ctx = locals() 
ctx.update(
    js_json1 = json1,
    TotVar = tot,
) 
return render(request, 'uploaded.html', ctx)
```

or

```
ctx = {
    'locals': locals(),
    'js_json1': json1,
    'TotVar': tot,
}
return render(request, 'uploaded.html', ctx)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: ok ! I have made these changes but how are they to be handled in the javascript ? My javascript doesn't seem to work.